# JS dealing with 'input' button info

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm pretty much new to JS and html, so I'm sorry in advance if you find this question too primitive..

I'm trying to do a simple login-logout page. I succeed to switch between the two displays (once one is logged-in or logged-out), but I still have one problem left:
how can I 'delete' the username+password details from the last log-in session when I press 'logout'?

In other words, how can I set the 'password' and 'text' input types to be clear (without any information inside them), **using Java Script, preferably with JQuery**?

Comment: log om and log out is usually done on the server-side.

Comment: maybe you can use php for this, check `session_destroy()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#username').val("")
    $('#password').val("")
})
```

That should clear both of your inputs every time you load the page.

But as Ibu said, You should handle logins with Php serverside.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to clean all your input text just use a simple script like:

```
$("input[type=text]").val('');
```

Pass all input's with type text will have the value empty.

You can bind this with your cancel button or even after post the form with confirm button.

Binding with cancel button example (you will need a button with ID="cancel" to this work):

```
$("#cancel").click(function() {
    $("input[type=text]").val('');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The other answers are all good... using `.val('')` would do the trick.

I'm going to go a little beyond what you're asking for since it might be useful to you and other readers. Here's a general form reset function...

```
function resetForm(formId) {

    $(':input', $('#' + formId)).each(function() {
        var type = this.type;
        var tag = this.tagName.toLowerCase(); // normalize case

        if (type == 'text' || type == 'password' || tag == 'textarea') {
            // it's ok to reset the value attr of text inputs, password inputs, and textareas
            this.value = "";
        } else if (type == 'checkbox' || type == 'radio') {
            // checkboxes and radios need to have their checked state cleared but should *not* have their 'value' changed
            this.checked = false;
        } else if (tag == 'select') {
            // select elements need to have their 'selectedIndex' property set to -1 (this works for both single and multiple select elements)
            this.selectedIndex = -1;
        }
    });
};
```

I hope this helps.